# Django-openauth-id documentation and installation guides

Tags: django, documentation, django-openid-auth

On a few questions [this package](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth) was recommended to provide Django with OpenAuth capabilities.

I'm new to Django and as one of my first projects, I'm trying to replicate StackOverflow's login and registration mechanisms. the only two documents that relate to the usability and installation of the package are the [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~django-openid-auth/django-openid-auth/trunk/view/head:/openid.txt) and [openid.txt](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~django-openid-auth/django-openid-auth/trunk/view/head:/openid.txt) files. ***edit*** I forgot to mention the example in their code base ***/endedit***

I implemented what the files and example implemented, but so far I still feel lost in terms of actually understanding how the mechanism works and how to build a site with openauth-id integration.

The questions I have involve:

1. Best practice way to include multiple openID providers
2. Proper way to connect the to the Django-user models
3. Handling any security, privacy, etc issues that may arise

Answer (score 3):

I have put up an example of using django-openid-auth with openid-selector(http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) for a nice UI on github. See if this helps.

https://github.com/rajasaur/openid_userprofiles

If something is not clear from the examples, please ask and Id be more than happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Imho:
You need to include each ID provider in a separate Authentication backend.
Bast practice is also to use build in User model.
Look for example plugin that provides multiple authentication providers
[django-social_auth at github](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth).
Hope that will help...